# Simple user registration like Stack OverFlow?

Tags: web-applications, single-sign-on

One of the features that really impressed me with Stack Overflow was the simple user registration. This is something I would like to implement on my sites. I've currently been using alot of Drupal and have found the Janrain Engage (formerly RPX) module. It enables simple registration using third party accounts but not as clean as Stack Overflow.

Does any one have any guidance on how to implement this as simple as possible?

Thanks.

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into a system such as [OpenID](http://openid.net/add-openid/), which will allow users to "log in" to your site using their login information from OpenID participating systems (such as the ones allowed by Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 0):

try a simple plugin from [drupal.org/files/projects](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects) - see here for [the direct download](http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/openid-5.x-1.5.tar.gz) for your drupal site!

;-)